React Native app doesn't load with BorderRadius
I have two views, and I added BorderRadius: 10 to them. The problem is, when I load the app, the views show up with sharp corners, like the BorderRadius isn’t being applied. But if I edit the code (for example, change it to another value and then back to 10), it updates correctly on the screen.
It’s like the BorderRadius doesn’t work on the initial load but works fine after any code change triggers a refresh. Has anyone run into this issue before? How can I get the BorderRadius to work right from the start?
  sunSquere: {
    height: 130,
    width: 130,
    marginTop: 340,
    marginRight: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },

<View style={[styles.sunSquere, {backgroundColor: graphColour}]}>
  <Text style={[{ color: textColour, fontSize: 18, }]}>Sunrise: {sunrise}</Text>
  <Text style={[{ color: textColour, fontSize: 18, }]}>Sunset: {sunset}</Text>
  </View>



